# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services need to repair

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2012

I had SQL 2012 installed with SSRS. Then I was playing with IIS and deleted (I think) ReportServer aliases and webs

Now I need to work with SSRS but can't figure out how to return it back. Service is running, but I have no websites. I tried to start SQL 2012 install and repair/remove but nothing like this available, SSRS checked and grayed out.

I checked Add/Remove programs and no luck either, Can't find SSRS listed.

I really don't want to reinstall SQL 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I checked Add/Remove programs and no luck either, Can't find SSRS
>   listed.

That's because it's not listed as SQL Server Reporting Services. You will need to choose SQL Server in the list of installed programs, click "Uninstall/Change", select the instance of SQL Server that you want to work with, then finally in the 'Select Features' interface, check only 'Reporting Services' and uninstall.

Then you can re-install after that has all been removed.